# Game Score Projection Regression Model Accuracy Improvement?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm creating a regression model to project scores of a basketball game. Here are my training results:

**loss: 9.4327 - val_loss: 9.4029**

I've tried adding more features, messed around with the model (dense layers, hyperparameters), I can't seem to get it any lower.

Is this just due to the nature of this specific problem? I'm sure there can be some improvements but how meaningful an improvement is my question. I just trying to get some input from someone with a more expertise and **not asking for you to write any code for me**.

Here is what my test predictions plot looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the loss you're seeing is due to the inherent unpredictability of basketball scores. Inherent unpredictability refers to the natural uncertainty or randomness in an event or outcome. In this context, it means that basketball scores can be influenced by many unpredictable factors (like player performance on a particular day), making them hard to predict accurately all the time. However, there are a few things you could try:

1. Model Complexity: If your model is too simple, it may not capture all the nuances in your data. Try Bagging or Boosting models.
2. Regularization: This can help prevent overfitting and improve generalization performance. Try Ridge or Lasso.
3. Ensemble Methods: Combining predictions from multiple models often results in better performance.

Comment: Thank for the response. I will definitely look into your suggestions.

Comment: Good luck with it. Please do post if you improve the score or not so someone else can help as well